# Headless Ubuntu 16.10 server not recognizing UTF-8 special characters

Tags: 14.04, command-line, server, vim, locale

I have installed Ubuntu Server 16.10 headless on my Virtual Machine.
When I type any special character in my terminal or vim file, the characters are not recognized, instead I just see dots.

There is an image below that shows the problem I am facing:

[image]

Those 4 characters are exclamation marks.

Also, since it does not accept these characters, I am unable to quit vim without saving.

Comment: Check your language and keyboard settings.

Comment: Maybe you are missing some fonts. Please show us examples of "special characters" which are not displayed properly.

Comment: I was able to solve by setting up my machine again but this time did not setting up my keyboard manually... the manual set up did not consider any special characters(not even numbers)...